# Transform time series to same length

Tags: r, time-series, transformation

I am looking for a way to transform time series of different length into a unique length.
I think this question has already been asked by I can't find it. I guess I am just not using the right vocabulary for the question.

Data 1: 20 variables x 250 observations (time points)

Data 2: 20 variables x 50 observations (time points)

I would like to transform these data into 100 observations while keeping the shape of curves for the 20 variables in both cases.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post some data and your best attempts at code please.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(0, 250, 20)
data[1, ] <- rnorm(20)
for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {
  data[i, ] <- data[i - 1, ] + rnorm(20, 0, 0.02)
}
rownames(data) <- 0:249
```

One way of handling this is with `reshape2` and `dplyr`:

```
library("reshape2")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
molten <- melt(data, varnames = c("Time", "Variable"))
```

Plot of original data:

```
ggplot(molten, aes(x = Time, y = value, colour = factor(Variable))) + geom_line()
```

[image: Plot of original data]

Now reduce the `data.frame` by a factor of 5 using means of the values in each time period:

```
shorter <- molten %>%
  group_by(Variable, Time %/% 5) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value), Time = mean(Time))
```

Plot new data:

```
ggplot(shorter, aes(x = Time, y = value, colour = factor(Variable))) + geom_line()
```

[image: Plot of shorter data]

If you want original wide form of data:

```
shorterWide <- acast(shorter, Time ~ Variable)
```

Comment: You could do that. It depends on what type of smoothing you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a way using this function
[Basic two-dimensional cubic spline fitting in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611491/basic-two-dimensional-cubic-spline-fitting-in-r)

I guess the keyword I was missing was cubic spline.

In my case I want to do something like that

spline(Data1, n = 100)
spline(Data1, n = 100)